# Using Interface to implement code on all activities

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement some code on every activity and don't want to copy and page the code into each activity.

Originally I just had a parent activity with the code then extended all of the others but I couldn't do this on ListActivities or ExpandableListActivities.

I think this will be done by using an interface class then having each activity implement this.  However when I try to do this Eclipse gives me an error and says to remove the method body.

Here is what I have so far

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public interface MenuOptions {

  /**
     * Method called when the hardware menu button is called. Uses optionmenu.xml for layout
     */
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Event listener for the options menu. If home is pressed user is sent to home screen. If settings is pressed user is sent to setting screen
     * User is passed as an extra
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent nextIntent = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home:     
                        Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        nextIntent = new Intent(this, Home.class);

                      break;
            case R.id.settings:     
                        Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        nextIntent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
                      break;

        }

        nextIntent.putExtra("user", user);
        startActivity(nextIntent);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: nice question, i would be eager to know interesting answers.

Answer (score 2):

`Interface` classes in Java should only contain method signatures and no implementation. Therefore you have to create a base class:

```
public class MenuOptions extends Activity {
  /**
     * Method called when the hardware menu button is called. Uses optionmenu.xml for layout
     */
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Event listener for the options menu. If home is pressed user is sent to home screen. If settings is pressed user is sent to setting screen
     * User is passed as an extra
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent nextIntent = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home:     
                        Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        nextIntent = new Intent(this, Home.class);

                      break;
            case R.id.settings:     
                        Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        nextIntent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
                      break;

        }

        nextIntent.putExtra("user", user);
        startActivity(nextIntent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And your activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends MenuOptions {
/*...*/
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but this solution still means I have three activites with nearly exactly the same code for Activities, ListActivities and ExplandableListActivities.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are not allowed to have method bodies. This is because it describes the *interface* of an object, not the method itself.

The problem with the same menu options shared by all activities is a common one. The easiest way of handling this is to define 2 or 3 superclasses (for ListActivities and MapActivities).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Looks like this may be the answer it just feels very clunky.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know an interface only describes what methods must be supported by a class implementing the interface.
This is the difference between implementing an interface and extending a class.
- so you can't write an interface thats used by all your classes, only define a set of methods which must be defined by any class implementing that interface

I would say your best bet is to create a new class which can be used by all your activities to do the same job. Then you'll need an instance of that class which is created and initialised by each activity onCreate (or somewhere else)

Alternately you may find you can make your new class static so you don't need to create an instance, just call a static method at the right times

One other way of doing it is to create a subclass of Activity which includes the standard behaviour and create all your activities as a subclass of this. Where you have ListActivities (for instance) you'll have to do some recoding, making them subclassed activities containing lists